# Outlook Web add-in: Is it possible to close the inspector window by add-in?

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I'm now developing an outlook web add-in. One of the feature is to move the email to trash. However, the behaviour of the add-in in outlook 2016 and OWA seems different.

When I double-click the email to open the inspector window and perform the add-in delete function:

> OWA: the inspector window will close automatically
>
> Outlook 2016: the inspector window will not close

As I want to achieve the same result in Outlook 2016 and OWA, I would like to know if any method can close the inspector window.

My add-in to delete the email is using EWS SOAP API "MoveItem". OWA works perfect but Outlook 2016 will not close the inspector window after delete.
I have tried to use the Office.js function "Office.context.mailbox.item.close()" but it seems only work for compose item.

Answer (score 1):

That is unfortunately the current behavior. I've encountered the same issue with my add-in and had to adjust by displaying a message to the user that they will have to close the window after my code moves the email to another folder. You can vote to include the ability to close read windows here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/